# Debugging Bison generated code with GDB

Tags: gdb, bison

I am trying to step into my yyparse function, which is defined in Bison generated code, but I get a message from GDB saying

> `Reading file "foo.tab.c"...No such file or directory.`

The file generated by Bison is called foo.cc.  Why is it looking for `foo.tab.c`, instead?

Answer (score 2):

The .cc file is really an input to the Bison program. The foo.tab.c is THE output -- a C file generated by Bison. It contains lookup tables to speed up parsing and some default definitions for most everything you'd need. This file **is** compiled and contributes to object code. You might find the [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_mono/bison.html#Bison-Parser) helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Input files for Bison should follow the yacc convention and be named foo.y. When processed the output file should be foo.tab.c. For C++ this is foo.yxx to foo.tab.cxx.

Are you using the -o or --output-file argument for Bison. This might be the problem, instead use the conventions mentioned.